Speeding up NMaximize for an optimisation problem in thousands of variables
I am trying to find the set of parameters that maximize the log-likelihood $f(\mathbf{x}) = \ln P(G|\mathbf{x})$ in an graph-based optimisation problem.
I have an expression of the form $f(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i}\alpha_{i} \log (x_i) + \sum_{i<j}\log(1-x_i x_j)$ with $\mathbf{x}= (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{3125})$, and $\mathbf{\alpha}$ a vector of real numbers, i.e the expression is very long and contains a large number of variables (representing nodes in a complex network).
I am using the following code to find the optimal parameters for $\mathbf{x}$, here with a random matrix to give the values of $\alpha$.
Qgreen = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {3125, 2726}];
len = Dimensions[Qgreen][[1]];
strength[i_] := Total[Qgreen[[i, All]]]
str = Table[strength[i], {i, 1, len}];
vars = Symbol["x" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[Length@str];
vals = NMaximize[
      Append[{Sum[str[[i]] Log[vars[[i]]], {i, 1, Length@str}] + 
         Total[Flatten@
           Log[1 - Table[
              Table[vars[[i]] vars[[j]], {i, 1, j - 1}], {j, 2, 
               len}]]]}, Table[0 <= vars[[i]] < 1, {i, 1, len}]], 
      vars, Method -> "NelderMead"][[2]] /. Rule -> List;

This is taking +1 day to complete, can anything be done to speed it up? I have tried adjusting the working precision, and the method, but it doesn't have any material impact on the overall speed. It may be best to just let it run on a high-performance computer, but perhaps something can be done in Mathematica to optimise the code?

If you consider something like the Shennon's entropy or maximal likelihood  , then the crucial restriction $ x_1+x_2+⋯+x_{3125}=1$ is omitted by you

Yes, this is important, though you can see it in the code segment, each variable $x$ is to be between 0 and 1, that is sufficient: Table[0 <= vars[[i]] < 1, {i, 1, len}].

Can you kindly elaborate you "that is sufficient"?

The $x$'s need to be used to build links in a graph with probability $x_{i}x_{j}$ between nodes $i$ and $j$, so we need a constraint that keeps the $x$'s giving probabilities, though you can also use $0 \leq x_i < 1$ it appears (see Squartini et al., New J. Phys, 2011). I don't think its necessary they sum to one.

I have  played with smaller numbers, decreasing accuracy, and obtained the following.
SeedRandom[1234]; Qgreen = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {591, 537}];
len = Dimensions[Qgreen][[1]];
strength[i_] := Total[Qgreen[[i, All]]]
str = Table[strength[i], {i, 1, len}];
vars = Symbol["x" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[Length@str];
NMaximize[Append[{Sum[str[[i]] Log[vars[[i]]], {i, 1, Length@str}] + 
 Total[Flatten@Log[1 - Table[
 Table[vars[[i]] vars[[j]], {i, 1, j - 1}], {j, 2, len}]]]}, 
 Table[0 <= vars[[i]] < 1, {i, 1, len}]], vars, 
 Method -> "NelderMead", AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4] // Timing


{229.547, {-1.20732*10^7, {x1 -> 0.322403, x2 -> 0.275831,...,x591 -> 0.321412}}}

The Method->"RandomSearch" option produces a better result, but approximately 100 times slower. Hope this will be useful.

A simple estimate for the objective function from below can be obtained by putting all the variables equal to 1/2: Sum[str[[i]] Log[1/2], {i, 1, Length@str}] +   Total[Flatten@Log[1 - Table[Table[1/4, {i, 1, j - 1}], {j, 2, len}]]] results in -1.10403*10^7 which is better than obtained by NelderMead. In your case {3125, 2726} that estimate equals -2.96669*10^8.
